# Incorrect results for Solr search with multiple terms

Tags: solr

Perhaps someone can enlighten me on how Solr matches terms. So I have a string attribute named assignedBy, and I do a query against this attribute with the value "Aaron Mason" (no quotes). Solr returns more matches than I anticipated because the term "Mason" also matches documents whose other fields contain the word "Mason" in it. By turning on debugging feature (from Solr admin), I see Solr breaks down the query into two attribute queries - "aaron" for assignedBy and "mason" for the catch-all *text* (see below). Is this the correct behavior? How do I ensure that it only finds matches against the attribute I specify? Thanks.

`"debug":{
    "rawquerystring":"assignedBy:Aaron Mason",
    "querystring":"assignedBy:Aaron Mason",
    "parsedquery":"assignedBy:aaron _text_:mason",
    "parsedquery_toString":"assignedBy:aaron _text_:mason",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you are correct. when you `q=assignedBy:Aaron Mason`
after parsing the query, based on you query tokenizers in schema file, it looks like
`assignedBy:aaron` and `_text_:mason`.

if you don't specify field name queryterm is searched in default field (which is set in solrconfig.xml file) you can look for `<str name="df">text</str>` under `/select` handler. in your case it might be `_text_`.

So, Solr search for its index and retrieve combined results of all documents which has field `assignedBy` with term "Aaron" and all documents which has field `_text_` with term "mason".

you might have used copyfield to copy some field values to *text* field. check for it.

**You can use dismax/edismax where you can specify in which field all your terms to search for**
example:

`q=Aaron Mason&wt=json&debugQuery=on&defType=dismax&qf=assignedBy`

This only finds matches against the field "assignedBy" specified in `qf`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and suggestion!